# Is there any alternative way to download kaggle competition data in Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am trying to use google colab for Kaggle Competitions. However, everything went fine until I tried to download the data. I got **403 - Forbidden** error.
 I am able to download other competition's data such as **us-consumer-finance-complaints** but not the **LANL-Earthquake-Prediction** data.

Initial Step:
To move kaggle.json into the folder where the API expects to find it,

```
!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle/ && mv kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/ && chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

When executing the following code in colab,

```
!kaggle competitions download -c LANL-Earthquake-Prediction
```

I got the following error message,

```
403 - Forbidden
```

I don't know what's wrong, but unable to download the data from Kaggle. Is there anyway we can resolve the problem?

Answer (score 15):

I'm sorry I'm only seeing this 9 months later, but the solution I found was simple. So simple I got annoyed. Hopefully, someone else is spared the wasted hours.

**You need to accept the rules of the competition first!**

While logged in to Kaggle, go to the competition page and look at the menu tabs. You should see something like this:
[image]

Select the **'Rules'** tab and click on **'I Understand and Accept'**:
[image]

You should be good to go now.